# I have a Text file that contains paths and filenames, I want open explorer to each one

Tags: batch-file, concatenation

I have a Text file that contains the following information:

X:\Mr.Wizard\Desktop\Calibration Instruction\CUP CALIBRATION.doc

X:\Mr.Wizard\Desktop\Document\Instruction\Variance.doc

For the life of me, I am unable to determine how to open explorer to the path.  I keep trying to concatenate the variables filedrive and filepath into a variable called Exp_Path, however I get an empty variable so I just keep removing that portion of the code. Please help....

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
chcp 65001
@echo on
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\TestFileListing.txt) do (
   ECHO filedrive=%%~di
   ECHO filepath=%%~pi
   ECHO filename=%%~ni
   ECHO fileextension=%%~xi

   pause
   explorer.exe "%%~pi"
   del /P /F "%%i"
   echo "%%i" >> "Processedfiles.txt" 
)
endlocal
Echo Process Completed
set /p="Press Any Key to Continue"
```

Comment: Did you try `explorer.exe "%%~i"` just like that. For the content of each line in the file, that should do it I think.

Comment: You are trying too hard.  Try something like `for /f %%i in (C:\TestFileListing.txt) do start %%~dpi`.  Your real problem is probably that  `p` doesn't include the drive letter.  I just mocked up your test and mine works fine.  I get a batch of explorer windows in a neat little overlapping row pointing at the files within.

Comment: If you are trying to specifically fire up the explorer in that path, delete the file, write the results to another file, and move on, please be specific in your question and I will help you.  Your question and sample batch don't seem to match from my point of view.  Flag me so I see it please.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

chcp 65001 | cls

for /f delims^= %%i in ('type C:\TestFileListing.txt'
)do (
     echo; Drive=%%~di
     echo; Path=%%~pi
     echo; Name=%%~ni
     echo; Extension=%%~xi
    
     pause
     start "" /b explorer.exe "%%~fi"
     echo;del /p /f /a: "%%~fi"
     echo; "%%i" >>"Processedfiles.txt" 
    ) 

echo;Process Completed
timeou -1 | echo\Press Any Key to Continue...
```

---

Or...

```
@echo off

for /f delims^= %%i in ('type "C:\TestFileListing.txt"'
)do >>"C:\The\Full\Path\To\File\Processedfiles.txt" (
     start "" /b /min explorer.exe "%%~fi"
     echo;del /p /f /a: "%%~fi"
     echo;"%%i"  
    ) 

echo;Process Completed
timeou -1 | echo\Press Any Key to Continue...
```